# An object of mass of 1,200 kg accelerates from rest by a constant force of 2400 N. What is the velocity of the object after 8 secs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I know this question is impulse and momentum but im having a hard time putting it together

Comment: First of all: what kind of motion do you have here?

Answer (score 1):

Constant force, so constant acceleration from $F=ma$.

You can then find the velocity, $v$, of the object at a time $t$ from one of the suvat equations $v=u+at$.

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

To solve for the final speed using the impulse-momentum equation, we can use the formula:
$$m\Delta{v} = F\Delta{t}$$
Given the values: $m = 1200$ kg, $F = 2400$ N, and $\Delta{t} = 8$ s, and knowing that the initial speed is $0$, we can calculate the final speed.

The same can also be solved using Newton's second law, $F=ma$, and the definition of acceleration, $a = \Delta{v}/\Delta{t}$.